# What type of chart is this? does this have a specific name or it must be built from scrach?

Tags: html, css, charts, angular5, visualization

I am working on this chart angular 5 project and have a requirement of this chart but not able to figure out this chart name or it should be built custom any inputs. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's called a calendar heatmap, you can find examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=calendar%20heatmap&rlz=1C5CHFA_enFR920FR920&oq=calendar%20heatmap&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l7.4200j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check this